# What are these creatures the Avengers are fighting in "Infinity War"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

What are these creatures that the Avengers are fighting off in the "Infinity War" trailers? Are they aligned with or controlled by Thanos?

[image: Avengers Infinity War]

Comment: Generic alien baddies.

Comment: I'm voting to close this per our [Future Works policy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5187/should-questions-about-future-works-be-closed-as-primarily-opinion-based)

Comment: @Valorum definitely. Kinda getting tired of that. Just once I'd like to seem the Avengers go up against an organised army with generals and such.

Comment: @KutuluMike how could you?! A "we don't know" answer is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: They remind me always of Genestealers from Warhammer 40K.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### There seems to be a [pretty](https://www.cbr.com/avengers-infinity-war-agents-of-shield-missed-crossover/) [good](https://moviepilot.com/p/avengers-infinity-war-comics-history-outriders-thanos-servants/4324484) [consensus](https://hiddenremote.com/2017/12/03/avengers-infinity-war-trailer-reveals-thanos-army-made-outriders/) <sub><sup>(all separate links)</sup></sub> that they're the Outriders.

(And as [@Möoz](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/21267/m%c3%b6oz) confirms in the comments, they are indeed aligned with Thanos)

The Outriders were a race of genetically engineered parasite-assassins which solely to serve their master/creator. They live binary lives, they either complete their task or they fail.

[image: Evidence of description above]

The Outriders look incredibly similar to the alien that the Black Panther is fighting, both with four arms, no eyes and fangs.

[image: Outrider] [image: Black Panther fighting Alien]

[gif of fight](https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/SBK8-YOl-ks5apiAV6iiBQygLcw=/0x0:1280x532/1520x0/filters:focal(0x0:1280x532):gifv():no_upscale():background_color(f8f8f6)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/9776741/Outrider.gif)

Comment: And yes, they are aligned with Thanos

Comment: ^ Having watched _Infinity War_, I can confirm that they are indeed aligned with Thanos, or at least his henchman, Proxima Midnight.